# Woodmart theme logo replacement from all template

Tags: php, json, wordpress, wordpress-theming, themes

I have woodmart theme and i want to replace woodmart logo on all templates once they import the template.
so i am looking for a PHP code for child theme to replace default logo to my logo.

it should be work on all 70+ template so when user import any demo, it should be comes with my logo.
Thanks any help will be highly appreciated.

thi is how it should be once the import is complete
https://oliversites-templates.com/drinks/

Answer (score 0):

Login website/wp-admin dashboard menu in side show you a menu name is woodmart menu - header select header and edit change here logo with phone, desktop mode

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).